# Unable to import spark avro package in spark 2.3 "import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._" in Intellij

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, avro

Import Error in intellij
**import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._**
  image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvT19.png

Spark 2.3 doesnt support databrick avro, so steps to support avro below spark version 2.4 is given here https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-4.0/README-for-old-spark-versions.md

i have followed every steps still unable to import package import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._

My Spark Version is 2.3 and scala version is 2.11.8]
  image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdCE8.png

I have downloaded jar from here
  image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp6Kg.png

jar is added in intellij
  image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCgdu.png

Comment: Your goal is to load avro file to dataframe?

Comment: Does sbt build work?